# Is there a difference between calling Klass::[] and Klass[] in ruby?

Tags: ruby

This works Hash[...] and this is very similar to Hash::[...]. But how does this work internally - is there a difference? And also, does the Klass[] work because the method name starts with a special character? We can have a self method called "test" and definitely we can't do Klasstest.

Help me understand how this works internally in ruby.

Answer (score 3):

**Corrected Following suggestion from Jörg W Mittag**

The most general forms is:

```
receiver.method_name(arg)
```

When there is no ambiguity with a constant name, then the form above can be replaced with:

```
receiver::method_name(arg)
```

You can omit the parentheses:

```
receiver::method_name arg
receiver.method_name arg
```

For method names that fit a certain pattern, there is syntax sugar that allows for alternative ways to write.

- If the method name is `==`, `!=`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=`, `<=>`, `===`, `**`, `*`, `/`, `+`, or `-`, then you can write

  ```
  receiver method_name arg
  ```
- If the method name is `some_attribute=`, then you can write

  ```
  receiver.some_attribute = arg
  ```
- If the method name is `[]`, then you can write

  ```
  receiver[arg]
  ```

There is an exceptional pattern. If the method name is `some_prefix@`, then the only way to write is

```
    some_prefixreceiver
```

Comment: Note: `o::m` and `o.m` are only interchangeable if `m` doesn't start with an uppercase letter. If it does, then it may be interpreted as a constant lookup rather than a message send, depending on whether you pass an argument list.

Comment: @JörgWMittag I missed that. Thanks for noticing.

Comment: You can also write ```arr.[] 0``` or ```arr.[](0)```.

Comment: @Ernest That is what I mean by "the most general form" without and with the parentheses. The English word "alternative" as used here does not mean something is replaced by something else. It means there is an additional way.